# MemoryError in Django Sphinx!

Tags: django, sphinx

The whole error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/aaa/trysphinx/views.py", line 30, in <module>
    print list(results)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.4-py2.7.egg\djangosphinx\models.py", line 243, in __iter__
    return iter(self._get_data())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.4-py2.7.egg\djangosphinx\models.py", line 422, in _get_data
    self._result_cache = list(self._get_results())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.4-py2.7.egg\djangosphinx\models.py", line 557, in _get_results
    results = self._get_sphinx_results()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.4-py2.7.egg\djangosphinx\models.py", line 529, in _get_sphinx_results
    results = client.Query(self._query, self._index)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.4-py2.7.egg\djangosphinx\apis\api263\__init__.py", line 388, in Query
    response = self._GetResponse(sock, VER_COMMAND_SEARCH)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django_sphinx-2.2.4-py2.7.egg\djangosphinx\apis\api263\__init__.py", line 144, in _GetResponse
    chunk = sock.recv(left)
MemoryError
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're loading more data into memory than your computer can handle. Perhaps rather than:

```
print list(results)
```

…do:

```
for r in results:
    print r
```

Comment: Thank you ,but there is no use. I guess maybe some setting about memorry in the mysql or django-sphinx or sphinx.

Comment: The line `self._result_cache = list(self._get_results())` in sphinx looks pretty suspicious. I suggest posting a bug to django-sphinx.

Comment: Could you give me some more details?

Comment: Well `list(...)` will load the entire thing into memory, which doesn't look good.

Comment: However, it suggests that i should define the version of sphinx in setting fild of Django, but I do not know the hex number 0x of version 2.0.1.